# Use VBA in Word 2010 to search and manipuate a string

Tags: vba, microsoft-word-2010, macros

I have a macro that uses wildcards to find a particular string.  I want to find another string within the result (preferably using wildcards), extract that substring and do something else with it.

I know how to do the first search in VBA, but how do I do the second then extract the result?

For example, I use Search and Replace with wildcards to find variations of this:  `Effective Date: [date]`

Then I need to extract the date and paste it somewhere else.  How do I find and extract the date from this string?

Comment: how about once you find the string, use `instr` to find the `:` and then take the rest of the string from that position?

Comment: Is `instr` available in Word?  When I did I quick web search the only results were for Excel